# "device unauthorized" message when trying to use ADB, but can't boot device to confirm authorization

Tags: adb, samsung, boot-loop

I managed to get stuck in a boot loop after installing the Chainfire 3D driver on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

I can boot into the recovery mode (and download mode) but when I try to establish a connection using `adb shell`, it says:

> error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.

Of course, I cannot boot my device to confirm authorization.

How can I use ADB without first being authorized?

Comment: ['adb devices' says unauthorized in TWRP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48528833/9165920)

Answer (score 0):

Boot into recovery mode, and connect your device to your computer; then mount your device's internal memory/SD card and download the corresponding [firmware](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2459734) for your device (ensuring that you have the **correct firmware, or you will brick your device!**).

After this, flash the [firmware](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2459734) via the recovery, bearing in mind that it will wipe the current version of Android from the device.
Samsung devices are usually very good, as they keep personal data such as music and photos separate from the system partition, and so your personal data should remain intact. With this in mind, **attempt to back-up your device first (your recovery function may have the ability to do this)**.

Try and establish a connection with ADB using the ramdump mode (usually Volume Down+Power+Home), and it may work.
Otherwise, ADB requires a fully functioning device to work (for security reasons).

Before installing something that modifies the way your device works (such as Chainfire's mods, Beats' sound driver, etc), **always back-up your device first!** Only you can be blamed for not taking a backup before you installed the mod.

Answer (score 0):

You can't authorize adb. But anyway from recovery only the type of adb available is adb sideload. Sideload official OTA package or Flash the phone using ODIN if you want to ever boot it again. And where was adb shell anyway? Since adb shell works on a totally boot device or without using computer while on TWRP Terminal?

Answer (score -2):

boot into downloading mode connect with odin and install new rom from [sammobile](https://www.sammobile.com/) (find your firmware)

Comment: How does that answer the question – which is "How can I use adb without first being authorized?" Even with a new firmware, the device must be authorized.

Comment: @Izzy Because installing a new ROM would fix the bootloop. You don't need `adb` at all for this.

Comment: @DanHulme true in this specific case, which is why it should be part of the answer *including an explanation* ;)